# Accessing FCurve from context returning None

Tags: python, graph-editor, fcurves

I'm trying to write a simple function that will select the keyframes in-between 2 frames and have got the following:

```
def SelectInbetween():
    activeCurve = bpy.context.active_editable_fcurve
```

It's not much now as I'm trying to access this variable from python before manipulating it. But it keeps returning None. I don't know why and would appreciate any help

Comment: Hi and welcome! Do you mind to elaborate on "in-between 2 frames"? Do you like to specify the start and end frame? Or are they selected somehow?

Comment: blender uses context.  To use the `context.selected_editable_fcurve` AFAIC requires it being run from the graph editor context, not the console not the text editor.  If you edit the simple operator template to print the active fcurve, and add a button or menu to it in the graph editor space it will quite likely work as expected.

Comment: @brockmann I'll select 2 keyframes in the graph editor and would like to call this function to find all keyframes inbetween

Comment: @batFINGER I was selecting it from the graph editor then going to the scripting workspace to run it. Still was getting a None with both selected_editable_fcurve and the original script above

Comment: Not the same.  If run the code `print(context.area.type)` we want the result to be 'GRAPH_EDITOR' ... eg wrap your code with `context.area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR` ..will put the text editor area into graph . `print(context.selecterd_editable_fcurve)`  .... then back `context.area.type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'`   The code of an operator is invoked by pressing a button or selecting a menu in its designated area. This IMO is the issue here.

Comment: @batFINGER that works like a charm. Could I ask a follow up, which would how would I get the selected keyframes from those curves?

Comment: `[kf for kf in fcurve.keyframe_points if kf.select_control_point]`